# Stratified Sampling $E(E(X \mid \mu, \sigma))$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, monte-carlo

Let $X$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ be random variables.  I want to estimate $E(X)$ using Monte Carlo.  I am able to sample from, and know in closed-form, both the conditional distribution of $X \mid (\mu, \sigma)$ and the joint distribution of $(\mu, \sigma)$, but not the marginal distribution of $X$.  To use the information I have, I write
$$
E(X) = E(E(X \mid (\mu, \sigma))).
$$
A crude estimator would be
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{ij},
$$
where $X_{ij}$ is the $j^{th}$ observation in the sample from the conditional distribution $X \mid \mu_i, \sigma_i$. This requires $N$ samples, each of size $n$.

I understand that stratified sampling is a good candidate for variance reduction in such a scenario, but I'm not sure how to use it in this case.  For stratified sampling we partition the range of $(\mu, \sigma)$ into $K$ strata $A_1, \ldots, A_K$  such that $\sum_{i=1}^K P((\mu, \sigma) \in A_i) = 1$.  Letting $p_i = P((\mu, \sigma) \in A_i)$ we then write
$$
E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \,E(X \mid (\mu, \sigma) \in A_i),
$$
and draw samples from $X \mid (\mu, \sigma) \in A_i$ to estimate the expectations.  I know $p_i$ since I know the joint distribution of $(\mu, \sigma)$, but I can't figure out how to sample from $X \mid (\mu, \sigma) \in A_i$; rather, only $X \mid (\mu, \sigma)$, meaning only when $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are given values.

The example I have in mind is $X \mid \mu, \sigma \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, with some continuous uniform distribution on $(\mu, \sigma)$.  How can I generate samples from $X \mid (\mu, \sigma) \in A_i$?

Comment: $X_{ij}$ would be the $j^\text{th}$ observation in the sample from the conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mu_i,\sigma_i$.  It would not be the $j^\text{th}$ sample; that is an incorrect way of using the word "sample".  Rather than saying it requires $N\cdot n$ samples, you should say it requires $N$ samples, each of size $n$. $\qquad$

Comment: Where you wrote $\displaystyle \frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^n$, did you mean $\displaystyle \frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^N$? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy good points, edited.